# stopping random choose existing option

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my game, when the "next-question" button is clicked, it should choose a new word in the grid for the user to spell. It does this, but the problem is that instead of going to another word, sometimes the randomization brings it back to the word it is already on. I need to make it so that it chooses any other than the one its on.

```
    //Next question click event
    $('.next-question').on('click', function () {
    $('td').removeClass('highlight-problem');
    var r = rndWord;
    while (r == rndWord) {
    rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
}
    //Adds and removes nesesary classes
    $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('highlight-problem');
    $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wrong-letter').removeClass('wrong-word').removeClass('right-letter');
    var spellSpace = $('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').hasClass('right-word');
    if (spellSpace) {
        $(".next-question").eq(($(".next-question").index($(this)) + 1) %$(".next-question").length).trigger("click");
    } else {
        $("#hintSound").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
        hintSound.play();
        $("#hintPic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
        $('#hintPicTitle').attr('title', listOfWords[rndWord].hint);
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't the `while` loop already take care of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the value of `rndWord` before your while loop? It looks like a scoping issue - you either need to declare `rndWord` outside your function so it's preserved between calls or pass it in every time.

```
var rndWord;

function() { 
    //Next question click event
    ....
    var r = rndWord;
    while (r == rndWord) {
        rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
    }
```

After further clarification:

```
var currentWord;
function ClickEventHere() {
    r = currentWord;
    while (r == currentWord) {
        nextIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
        currentWord = listOfWords[nextIndex];
    }
    ...
}
```

There's no point in comparing an integer `r` with an array as you're doing in your while statement - you can either store the index or the word itself in a global and then check to make sure it's not being reused.

After this loop, `currentWord` will contain the next, different word

Comment: Then, can you answer my first Q... What does a debugger tell you it holds before the while loop is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Find random word, compare to last found if the same find another. Provided you have a decent number of words it should be enough.